# AppStore: Requires iOS 4.2 or later? But I set valid architectures to armv6 and armv7 and BaseSDK: Latest  iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, itunes

What dose "Requires iOS 4.2 or later " mean?  ... that it won't work on devices with iOS 4.3 or newer?   What was "Valid Architectures" for then?  Or BaseSDK:  Latest iOS (iOS 5.0) for?

So what do I need to do to make sure it is compatible with iOS 5.0?

Thanks...

Comment: so then I am refusing anyone less than iOS 4.2 ?  That isn't good either.  What can I do about that... thanks.

Comment: u can chance the target version of ur project but u gotta test if ur code is able to run in older ios systems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Requires iOS 4.2 or later"** mean that any device running iOS 4.2 through iOS 5.1.1 *(as of June 5, 2012)* can **install** and run your application.

Any user running iPhone OS 1.0 through iOS 4.1.x will not be able to install your app and the AppStore *(on device)* app will refuse the user to proceed with any purchase or download.

### Update

See the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html), specifically **Base SDK and Deployment Target Settings**.

Comment: Where is any Apple announcement on this?

Comment: Sorry, just misunderstood you answer. I thought you say Apple no more accepts apps compatible with 4.1 or lower. :)